# Identifying Post back or not

Tags: apex, httprequest, httpresponse

Is there a standard way to identify a post back in apex?(something like `IsPostBack` in asp.net? ) 
For a oauth flow I'm handling this with the controller constructor like

```
public class DeveloperTesting{        
    String code{get;set;}

    public DeveloperTesting(){
        try{
            code = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('code');  //first load code=null and in the post back it has the value
            System.debug('Access Code : '+code);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.debug('Error : '+e.getMessage());
        }
    }    
}
```

This is working for the use case but good to know if there is a standard way.